# okhttp3: 'ResponseBody' used without 'try'-with-resources statement

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, okhttp

I'm using okhttp3 and I'm trying to get the response errorBody like this:

```
ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
```

Android Studio gives me the following warning:

```
'ResponseBody' used without 'try'-with-resources statement
```

How to properly get the `errorBody`?

Answer (score 5):

From okhhtp3's documentation:

> **The response body must be closed.**
> Each response body is backed by a limited resource like a socket (live network responses) or an open
> file (for cached responses). Failing to close the response body will
> leak resources and may ultimately cause the application to slow down
> or crash.

From Oracle's documentarion:

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
> or more resources. A resource is as an object that must be closed
> after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources
> statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the
> statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which
> includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as
> a resource.

So, you should consume the errorBody like this:

```
try (ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody()) {
    if (errorBody != null) {
        String  errorBodyStr = errorBody.string();
        // Do something with the result. E.g. parse the JSON
    } else {
        // Do something if the errorBody is `null`
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO
}
```